# Увидит ли компьютер разделы жёсткого диска по usb

Tags: windows, hdd, ноутбук

У меня есть старый ноутбук, на котором есть несколько нужных мне файлов. Жёсткий диск разделен на томы (С: - винда, D: - файлы). Смогу ли я вернуть файлы из раздела D:, если подключу жёсткий диск по usb к другому ноутбуку?

Если да, то я немедленно заказываю себе переходник SATA-usb

Comment: Увидит, а переходник давно надо было заказывать, полезная в хозяйстве вещь) Только лучше брать переходник USB 3.0 (для скорости) и с блоком питания — тогда можно будет подключать и большие 3.5" диски тоже

Comment: ну конечно, если диск не залочен/запаролен. А так да, читаться будет. Единственное, что скорее всего удивит - это буквы будут другие (два диска C на одном компе немного необычно:) )